# Re-sizing WPF Geometry Path

Tags: wpf, geometry-path

I'm working on a WPF application. Given a geometry string path, such as:

```
F1 M 27,18L 23,26L 33,30L 24,38L 33,46L 23,50L 27,58L 45,58L 55,38L 45,18L 27,18 Z
```

Is it possible to scale the drawing to a width and height (no matter how small/large the original was) while keeping the figure as a whole, and then finally return the string path representation of the new scaled figure?

Comment: Perhaps use an IValueConverter and scale the value there based on a parameter given? I'm not sure if the Data property gets passed in as a String like that, or an array of data points, but it should be possible either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to scale the values in a path geometry string. Just put it in the `Data` property of a `Path` control and set its `Width`, `Height` and `Stretch` properties as needed:

```
<Path Data="F1 M27,18 L23,26 33,30 24,38 33,46 23,50 27,58 45,58 55,38 45,18 27,18 Z"
      Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Black"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it! The only thing you need to do, is to use a `Viewbox` for wrapping the item. This is a sample with a code that I had done, in this case I used the geometry as a `DrawingBrush`

```
...
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="Field" Stretch="Uniform">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{StaticResource FieldGrassBrush}" Geometry="F1 M 91.733,119.946C 92.8352,122.738 93.9374,125.529 92.9241,129.209C 91.9107,132.889 88.7819,137.458 84.4263,139.271C 80.0707,141.084 74.4885,140.142 70.8885,137.982C 67.2885,135.822 65.6707,132.444 65.1819,129.182C 64.693,125.92 65.333,122.773 65.973,119.626L 0.16,53.9203C 0.444319,53.4758 0.728638,53.0312 3.48413,48.7023C 6.23962,44.3733 11.4663,36.16 18.5596,28C 25.653,19.84 34.613,11.7333 
                ........
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
</UserControl.Resources>
...
```

Then the View Box (Note that the Grid has fixed `Height` and `Width`, but it will be stretched to the Viewbox's size, in this case, in an uniform way):

```
...
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid Height="300" Width="390">
        <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource Field}" StrokeThickness="0"/>
...
```

Comment: You won't *need* a Viewbox for this. You could as well simply use a Path and set its Stretch property to Uniform or UniformToFill. Anyway, the question was how to get back the scaled geometry as a string in WPF property path syntax.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your response. By setting the stretch property to "UniformToFill", it began working for me. That was the final property that I was missing. Can you add this as an answer so that I can mark it correct?